# Total no of posts of facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook

Is there any way to get the total number of posts which were updated in my facebook wall? I need to display the count of the total no.of posts which were updated in my facebook wall.

Comment: I have used the Shareon feature to update the post on my wall.

Comment: Getting total sum of posts is a little difficult thing, though you can use FQL with limit 5000 to get posts until some date and display count of the result.

Comment: But I have seen the website at http://www.espncricinfo.com/champions-league-twenty20-2012/content/current/story/586635.html and this has got both the "tweets" as well as "like". How is this possible ?

Comment: Have you guys got any solution?